# Syntax for accessing Variables in public Settings Class

Tags: c#, xaml, sharedpreferences, maui

I found following thread:

> After a lot of struggling to find the right answer, I was able to use
> [Preferences][1] to really easily get/set user settings without having
> to worry about saving and loading myself.
>
> ```
> // getter
> var value = Preferences.Get("nameOfSetting", "defaultValueForSetting");
>
> // setter
> Preferences.Set("nameOfSetting", value);
> ```
>
> I wrapped mine in a property so it's easier to use:
>
> ```
> public string FilePath
> {
>     get { return Preferences.Get(nameof(FilePath), ""); }
>     set { Preferences.Set(nameof(FilePath), value); }
> }
> ```

I tried a lot but cant manage to use the variables when wrapped in a property.

e.g. if I want to set the Labeltext to the Filepath setting from thread above:

```
Text = StandardSettings.get(Filepath);
```

or

```
Text = StandardSettings.Filepath{get};
```

The class StandardSettings is public and connected by "using" in my xaml.
What would be the syntax for getting/setting the Filepath?
Would be great to get the syntax for both xaml and c#.

Comment: `Text = StandardSettings.get(Filepath);` should be `Text = StandardSettings.FilePath;` See [properties docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties). If you were to set the value, use `StandardSettings.FilePath = whatever;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a new project and everything worked correctly. Here is my code:

```
public partial class NewPage1 : ContentPage
{
      public string FileName
      {
            get { return Preferences.Default.Get(nameof(FileName),"NoName"); }
            set { Preferences.Default.Set(nameof(FileName), value); }
      }

      public NewPage1()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            this.FileName = "Hahaha";
            (sender as Button).Text = this.FileName;
    }
}
```

When I clicked the button, the button's text will change as **Hahaha**. And if I remove the `this.FileName = "Hahaha";`, it will be the default value **NoName**.

Note: `this.FileName = "Hahaha";` will call the **FileName**'s set method. And `(sender as Button).Text = this.FileName;` will call its get method.

Comment: thanks! So I dont have to explicite call get6 or Set, but the method will be chosen by context. would it be correct to assume that if the variable is defined in another public class "StandardSettings", that "this.Filename" would become "StandardSettings.FileName" with StandardSettings class imported at top with "using"?

Comment: If it is defined in another public class "StandardSettings", first of all, you need to create an instance of the class "StandardSettings". Such as `var standard = new StandardSettings()`, and then use it such as `standard.FileName`. @canedha

Comment: ah i see. if i use the variable in another page/view i have to create another instance of the class, i guess? is there a way to have a global instance, that i create at startup and is accessable everywhere - or would that be bad practice? @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: You can make it be static variable. Such as `public static string FileName`. And then you can use it such as `StandardSettings.FileName`. @canedha